# UWP NavigationView Pane Display Top

Tags: uwp

I can not find any way of displaying the `NavigationView` at the top of the screen.
The `PaneDisplayMode` property [described in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.panedisplaymode) does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work you need to target and run Windows 10 version 1809 and later as described in the docs:

> **Additional features and requirements**
>
> Device family
>   Windows 10, version 1809 (introduced v10.0.17763.0)
>
> API contract
>   Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v7)

Alternatively you will be able to use the [Win UI library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/) which provides backward compatiblity of new control features into older versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Has this helped? If it resolved your problem, consider marking the answer as solution so that the question completed.